# css - placing a cta over a background image in a certain position on all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, image

First off sorry if this question is too newbie or it can't even be done.

This is currently where the CTA goes in relation to the background image
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjcuN.png)

This is where I want it to be
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwwq.png)
( essentially following the girl's gaze up to the CTA)

Apparently this cannot be done and render properly on all screen sizes. I anticipated mobile would be a problem -
< I can always change the image for mobile if need be>
But I was hoping to get this arrangement on desktop at least.

Can it be done?

Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: Even if someone doesnt have time to help me with the code.. ive spent so much time already... just a quick it can/cant be done would be SUPER helpful at this point